# Managing big project using single entity model

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, git, entity-framework

In our app we are using one entity model with database first approach and we have one db schema on the server. We are also using git for source control management.

Problems occur when some of us developers are working on new features that require database changes and that's happening frequently so our solution at the moment is the following:

1. Create a new branch from the master branch.
2. Make a new db for testing that is the same as the one that we use it live.
3. When finished with the new functionality transfer to the master branch and pull it from the newly created one, take the new entity model with the new db change and apply the sql on our live db when doing  a publish.

The problems happen if we stay too long on some new branch because we are switching branches a lot.

In that time our master branch changed a lot and also the live db with it, so our test db structure is a lot different from the time we created the new branch and then we have problems with merging our new branch with the master one.

We do it successfully every time, but it's difficult to manage it. I want to know if someone knows a better management system and it's workflow.

Comment: Do you use EF Migrations?

Comment: No we don't and i think that EF Migrations are used only in the Code First Approach.

Comment: My bad, missed the "db first". Code First approach fixes this problem with migration. I'd look into migrating to Code First to fix this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this bites.  The `.edmx` file constantly hits merge conflicts because it stores both domain configuration data and designer object placements.  (The former should be source controlled, the latter should be in a `.user` file.)  Add insult to injury: the file is designed to not be human readable (only managed by a tool) so it's very easy to fail when merging it.  It was this reason that caused us to ditch the `.edmx` ("database first") approach and move towards Code First.  A few carefully crafted unit tests that validate the entity classes match the table schema and we have a much, much simpler workflow.